# Incorrect object returned from a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models, `User` and `Discussion`

User model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :subscribed_discussions, :class_name => 'Discussion', :join_table => 'discussions_subscriptions'
has_many :discussions
```

Discussion model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :subscribed_users, :class_name => 'User', :join_table => 'discussions_subscriptions'
belongs_to :user
```

When I access discussions from a user `u.subscribed_discussions[0].user_id`, I get a completely different value of `user` than when I access the user directly from Discussion.find

```
system :029 > u.subscribed_discussions.first == Discussion.find(10)
 => true 
system :030 > Discussion.find(10)
 => #<Discussion id: 10, title: "MBA", content: "What do you think about management education, speci...", user_id: 7, created_at: "2011-01-24 21:44:22", updated_at: "2011-01-24 21:44:22", group_id: nil, profile_id: 8> 
system :031 > u.subscribed_discussions.first                       
 => #<Discussion id: 10, title: "MBA", content: "What do you think about management education, speci...", user_id: 1, created_at: "2011-01-24 21:44:22", updated_at: "2011-01-24 21:44:22", group_id: nil, profile_id: 8> 
system :032 > u.id
 => 1 
system :034 > Discussion.find(10).user_id
 => 7
```

`u` is a user who has *subscribed* to the discussion with id=10. When I access the discussion through the subscribed_discussions relationship, and access its user, I get `u` back, instead of the creator of that discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed this on IRC that this is a bug in HABTM relationships in Rails 3, if one of the table and the join table both have a column of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `Discussion` model `belongs_to :user`, which means the `user_id` field on the discussion model will be that user, it's unrelated to the `has_and_belongs_to_many :subscribed_users` association.

Can you post your models and schema.rb? It'll make it easier to understand what your model is doing.

Also, I suggest moving away from HABTM and using `has_many :through` instead, it'll give you a richer model.

Comment: I guess you missed the 2 lines of the models I've posted above. I've updated the question with some more clarification. If you still want a dump of schema.rb, let me know.

Comment: Oh I see now, that is weird. What rails version are you on? How are you creating the records?

Comment: I'm on 3.0.3. I'll try switching to 3.0.5 shortly. I'm doing something along the lines of `u.subscribed_discussions << @discussion unless u.subscribed_discussions.include? @discussion`.

Comment: Unfortunately, updating to 3.0.5 didn't help.